# How to change a WPF GroupBox Header on re-used UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, groupbox

I am looking for a way to change the header on a re-used user control from the containing XAML.

User Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ReusableControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
<GroupBox Header="Config Number">
    <Grid Name="MyConfig">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Name="Value1Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Value 1</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            IsEnabled="True" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Value1" StringFormat="{}{0:0.0#######}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" />
                </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>


        <Label Name="Value2Label" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Value 2</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            IsEnabled="True" Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Value2" StringFormat="{}{0:0.0#######}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" />
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>

     </Grid>
</GroupBox>

</Grid>
```

Containing Window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackExchangeQuestion"
Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config1" />
        <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config2" />
        <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

The intent being so that the successive controls say "Config 1", "Config 2", Config 3", rather than "Config Number" three times.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ReusableControl.xaml.cs` define a `DependencyProperty` like this:

```
public string Header
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Header",
        typeof(string), typeof(ReusableControl));
```

Now you can use this `Header` property as source of a Binding for the `Header` property of the internal `GroupBox`:

```
 <GroupBox Header="{Binding Header,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:ReusableControl}}">
```

Now you will see that this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config1" Header="Config 1"/>
    <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config2" Header="Config 2"/>
    <local:ReusableControl x:Name="Config3" Header="Config 3"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to add a xmlns:local line (to ReusableControl), and then it worked perfectly.